# Discord API - Get Discord role name from role ID

Tags: discord

I'm using the *Get Current User Guild Member* method of Discord API.

I successfully get back information about user such as their role in a specific guild

```
roles: ['705175621399216228']
```

How can I go from the role ID to the actual name of the role?

Comment: Are you using the raw discord api?

Comment: Yes, after accessing the auth token with auth2

Answer (score 0):

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-roles
You can get all the role objects of the guild and filter the roles with the ID of the role you require.
You can use node-fetch, etc to get the roles with something like this

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const data = await fetch("{base.url}/guilds/{guild.id}/roles")
const roleid = "xxxxxx"
const role = data.find(rl => rl.id === roleid)
```

Comment: That API path is awesome, although I get a 401 error message when I try to fetch it. Do you know which (if any) authorization is needed to get access to guilds' role?

Comment: Intents? DO you have the GUILD intent on when connecting to the websocket?

Comment: No, what is that? I have the oauth2 access token from user authentication, but I guess it is not required here

Comment: Yeah, MB can i see more of the error and how do your code

Comment: Here's my fetch request             fetch('https://discord.com/api/guilds/554623348622098432/roles', {
                headers: {
                    authorization: `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`,
                },
            })
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
            .catch(console.error);
            }
 `

And here's the error I get back 

` {message: '401: Unauthorized', code: 0}code: 0message: "401: Unauthorized"[[Prototype]]: Object `

Comment: I really can't make anything out from it. Can you use a binning service?

Comment: I solved it! The oauth2 doesn't give you access to that API call. You need to set up a bot application and then you can call it using the BOT auth token!

Comment: Wait? Aren't we working with bots already? Lol

Comment: @EnricoBottazzi Hi! I'm stuck here as well, would you mind elaborating on fetching the roles if you still happen to have the code around? I setup an app with a bot and have the bot token. But using it I still get 401 – what sort of authorisation did you use? Thank you!

Comment: @Cornelius, have a look at this => https://docs.google.com/document/d/11qp5cKpzOxHacz8IGsbXGZPABbf-Cgt9s3J1j9-Az7Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you! I thought perhaps you had found a way to do this without adding a bot to the server. It seems selfbot is the only solution to grab role names per user across all servers without adding a bot. Unfortunately it's against Discord T&C. I hope they will add an official API call at some point, seems odd to return role IDs but not names.